# Pillow image issues on Windows with Django

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have installed Pillow 2.9.0 through pip in my venv. When I try to upload a PNG image in Django REST framework I get an error as follow

```
"Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image."
```

But there is nothing wrong with the image. A JPG image gives the same result. Do I mis any modules?

Comment: downgrade pillow, latest got some bug (test on linux not windows)! @jelle

Comment: How is the upload done? Is the file written in binary mode?

Comment: Can you in your settings.py add
`from PIL import ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
` and try again? Maybe your file is not created properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to upload the image in Binary mode, this meant changing 'r' to 'rb' in my test case when opening the file.

Comment: This issue only seems to be occuring in Windows, not on Linux